# Updating Ruby 1.9.3 -> 2.0.0 without losing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

Have had 1.9.3p194 (RubyInstaller) with Ruby on Rails and all kinds of Gems installed on my WinXP. Now I want to update the whole setup.

Updating RoR (to 4.0.0) and gems was easy: `gem update rails`, `gem update --system`, `gem update`.

But how do I do that with Ruby? Is there an easy way to update the installation?

If not, and I have to install the fresh package, then how do I do it with little hassle?

I have downloaded the fresh 2.0 RubyInstaller. I have read that I shouldn't install this new Ruby version in the same directory as my old Ruby version (`c:\programs\Ruby`) that's why I chose a `c:\programs\Ruby200` directory. During the installation I clicked on every additional setting, including the "include new directory in the PATH variable" type of choice. But now when I type `ruby -v` I still get 1.9.3p194 and the new directory is absent from PATH (I haven't rebooted, so maybe this has something to do with it).

So how should I really install the new version? Should I simply change the old PATH to the new one? Or should I instead only add the new one without removing the old path (so there will be some kind of advantage of having both 1.9.3 and 2.0)? Or should I simply delete both installations and install 2.0 from the start?

How do I easily transfer the gems (or the list of them, so the `gem update` could handle the installation/updating) from my old installation to the new one?

I am using JetBrains RubyMine 5.4 editor, and would like to know if I need to do something there as well (for both the new and the existing projects).

Comment: You should use Bundler and a Gemfile, then once you've correctly installed the new Ruby, reinstall your bundle. (`bundle install`)

Answer (score 1):

Like many POSIX users, I rely on `rvm` and `bundler` to manage ruby versions & gemsets. Unfortunately, `rvm` is not available on windows. Although I haven't tried it personally, it looks like [`pik`](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) is a viable windows alternative. I would recommend checking that out.

You should also definitely look into [`bundler`](http://bundler.io/) if you're not already using it; since `bundler` is just a gem, it should be platform independent.